# is it possible to replicate directly between two pouchDB databases?

Tags: pouchdb

As per the question title, is it possible to replicate directly between two PouchDB databases?  I.e. without the PouchDB instances having to communicate through an intermediary CouchDB server?

I have looked through the PouchDB [API Replication documentation](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#replication) but could not see anything to suggest that a PouchDB instance can act in the role of a CouchDB server for replications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. In fact even peer-to-peer systems need an intermediary so they can at least find each other.

The closest thing to a p2p PouchDB out there right now is [PeerPouch](https://github.com/natevw/PeerPouch), but that also requires a CouchDB.